# Linear combinations and spanning solution spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

PLEASE  help on part A only :)

V = Column vectors [1 0 -1] and [1 3 0].

a) Make a system of 3 unknowns and 3 equations of which he solution space is spanned by V?

b) Express [1 2 3] as a linear combination of V, if possible.

I'm lost! I don't know where to start. Please don't skip steps in your explanation! Thanks.

Comment: By "[t]he solution space is spanned by V" do you mean the solutions make a subspace? In particular, is the zero vector $[0,0,0]$ also a solution?

Comment: Not sure, that is what the question says.

Comment: Then see my note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To a)**

The space spanned by $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,3,0)$ is a plane, since they are linearly independent. So, consider an equation of the form $ax+by+cz=0.$ $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,3,0)$ are solutions if $a-c=0$ and $a+3b=0.$ That is, $a=c=-3b.$ If $b=-1$ then $a=c=3.$

$$3x-y+3z=0$$ is one equation that has as solutions the plane spanned by $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,3,0).$ Any other equation having such a plane as solution must be a multiple of it. Thus a possible system is

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rrr} 3x-y+3z & = & 0\\ 6x-2y+6z & = & 0\\9x-3y+9z & = & 0\end{array}\right.$$

**To b)**

$(1,2,3)$ is linear combination of $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,3,0)$ if there exist $\alpha,\beta$ such that

$(1,2,3)=\alpha(1,0,-1)+\beta (1,3,0).$ That is,

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rrr}\alpha+\beta & = & 1\\ 3\beta & = & 2 \\ -\alpha & = & 3 \end{array}\right.$$  From the second equation you get $\beta=2/3$ and from the third one $\alpha=-3.$ Now, $$-\frac73=-3+\frac23=\alpha+\beta,$$ which contradicts the first equation. So, $(1,2,3)$ is not linear combination of $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,3,0).$

Comment: Thanks, but I already got an explanation! I need help on part A if anything!

Comment: Why is there an a,b,c, and d? and not just a,b,c?

Comment: Okay, I am sorry! I meant to put [1 3 0] as one of the column vectors. What changes?

Comment: I have edited my answer. My first thought was that you were asking for a system with solutions both vectors. Then I realized that the solution must be the vector space spanned by the given vectors.

Comment: Is there any way you can edit it to fit [1 3 0]? SORRY!

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: for a) so you can let b= some random number?

Comment: Yes. You are looking for one equation. If you take a different value $\ne 0$ you get an equation that it is a multiple, and so has the same solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you don't know where to start, I'll give you tips on starting. Note that your two starting vectors are linearly independent.

a) A system of 3 unknowns and equations spanned by two independent vectors can be defined by $3-2$ or $1$ equation(s) where the constant terms are zero. You can get other equations by multiplying that equation by any non-zero constant. To get the constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ for equation
$$ax+by+cz=0$$
solve these equations simultaneously:
$$a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 0 + c\cdot -1 = 0$$
$$a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 3 + c\cdot 0 = 0$$
Any solution will do for your first equation.

b) ... As I was typing this, NicNic8 gave a good answer for part b, so I'll just make one comment. If $[1,2,3]$ can be written as a linear combination of your two vectors, it will be a solution to the equation you get in part (a).

**NOTE:** My answer for part (a) assumes from your question that the solutions are "spanned" by your two vectors: in particular, the zero vector $[0,0,0]$ is also a solution. If it is not, my answer still works but there are also other answers to your question.

Comment: Did you mean $a*1+b*3+c*0=0$?

Comment: @Alyssa: No, I meant $a*1+b*3+c*1=0$ since the second given vector is $[1,3,1]$.

Comment: The second one is [1 3 0] MY BAD. I GOTTA EDIT THE QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

For part (b), Try to solve the following for $a$ and $b$:
$$a\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\-1\end{array}\right] + b\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\3\\1\end{array}\right]=\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}$$

This is three equations with two unknowns.  Use the first two equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.  Plug those values into the third equation.  If those values work, then you're done.  If not, then it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but mainly i'm confused on part A.